# unbind all click bound to elements classes

Tags: jquery, html, css, unbind

I want to unbind all clicks binded to an element via its classess

The elements are like this :

```
<i  class="icon-edit edit <%=AgentData.isSortiDeService(agent)%>" alt="<%=noteEchelle.getIdNote()%>"></i> //where isSortieDeService is a java method which returns a
```

string , the values of this string may be '' or 'isSortiDeService'

given that element like this may have some clicks binded like  :

```
//******************modifier la notation
       $(".edit").live("click",function(){ 
        var idNote = $(this).attr("alt");
         $("#divBody").empty();
         $("#divBody").load("<%=path%>/situationAdministrative/notation/editNote.jsp",{idNote:idNote});
         $("#divTitle").empty();
         $("#divTitle").append('Modifier la note');
         $("#div").css('width','650px');
         $("#div").modal({ dynamic: true });
          });
```

so i tried this

```
       $(".isSortiDeService").die('click').unbind("click").off("click").click(function(){
   alert("Cet agent n'est plus en service. Vous ne pouvez plus effectuer cette opération");
    });
  });
```

the click is not ubinded because it is binded to onther class even if it is the same element .

so i tried onther solution

```
  $('*').each(function(){
       if($(this).hasClass("isSortiDeService"))
       { $(this).die('click').unbind("click").off("click").click(function(){
       alert("Cet agent n'est plus en service. Vous ne pouvez plus effectuer cette opération");
        });

       }});
```

this also not working ,and the click is fired

i will express the problem like this : i have an element with multiple class, if my element has a specific class , i want to unbind all the clicks binded to others classes , but apprently unbind or off or die works for the same selector : so the same classe

any suggestion?

Comment: you're binding a click at the end `$(this).die('click').unbind("click").off("click").click(function(){` just try `$(this).off('click', function() { });`

Comment: no the problem is unbind works for clicks binded to the same selector , so if i unbind click on 'a class' ths click binded the 'anthoer class ' will fire , even if it the same element

Comment: instead of downvote , ask questions and will answer

Comment: I think OP is right when delegation is used, no?

Comment: then you need to specify the class which you want to bind click event to. `$(this).off('click', function() { $('.class').on('click', function () { }); });`

Comment: @Omar but i have multiple elements multiple classes , i want to generalize the code

Comment: why dont u just use `preventDefault()` and `stopImmediatePropagation()` if the clicked item has a specific class?

Comment: @Omar you suggestion is very good !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the below code if the clicked item has a specific class.

```
$(document).on('click', function (e) {
 if($(this).hasClass('class')) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopImmediatePropagation();
 }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

It has to be

```
$(".isSortiDeService").off('click');
```

To just remove all the click handlers attached to the element.

Comment: no the problem is unbind works for clicks binded to the same selector , so if i unbind click on 'a class' ths click binded the 'anthoer class ' will fire , even if it the same element

Comment: This is just the case when the 'other' element is 'on the same position' than the element from which you detach the event handler. This behaviour is normal and makes sense. If you want to remove all click handlers that are called if you click on a certain position, then you have to find all those elements and detach the click handlers from them.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try only

Remove all event handlers from element like this?

```
$(".isSortiDeService").off();
```

Comment: no the problem is unbind works for clicks binded to the same selector , so if i unbind click on 'a class' ths click binded the 'anthoer class ' will fire , even if it the same element

Answer (score 1):

As of jquery 1.7 the use of `.live` has been deprecated so you perhaps shouldn't use it anymore: http://api.jquery.com/live/

If you bind the click event using `.click` instead of `.live`, the element should have the event bound to it and then you can unbind this

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/qgbCz/)

Comment: Ya but .click doesn't then use delegation

Comment: you are using live method which is use to delegate event, see API doc. If you were not using some delegate, you won't have any problem to unbind event to a specific element

Comment: simple fix, if you want delegation use .on instead, you can still unbind in the same way:  http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/qgbCz/2/ (or use the `.off`)

Answer (score 1):

Well, this seems to be a workaround:

http://jsfiddle.net/cnu4u/

```
<div class="test test2"></div>
```

{ here for delegation used with .on() }

```
$(document).on('click','.test2',$.noop);
var arrClass = $('.test').attr('class').split(' ');
$.each(arrClass,function(i){
    $(document).off('click','.'+arrClass[i]);
});
console.log($._data(document,'events').click);
```

Comment: but this will create onther problem is some classes are common with other element

Comment: So if you want just to unbound event to a specific element, you should not use delegation (live or on or delegate) as its using a selector not specific to an element